# Can't save form i think the form is not valid how can i make it valid?

Tags: django, django-forms

view

```
def createitem(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form= itemform(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return Redirect('/items')
else:    
    form = itemform()
    return render(request, 'app/create.html', {'form':form})
```

here's the models if you see something wrong with it

```
class items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')


class itemform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = items
        fields = ['name','description','image']
```

I have already added this to settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL   = '/media/'
```

Comment: OK, so, the form is not valid. What is your question? (And why do you think the static settings are at all relevant?)

Comment: Also, Python doesn't use semicolons at the end of lines.

Comment: see the question now..

Answer (score 2):

just as Daniel Roseman said, you dont have "what if form is not valid" logic.
delete TAB before RETURN statement

```
def createitem(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form= itemform(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return Redirect('/items')
else:    
    form = itemform()
return render(request, 'app/create.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this is not a straight answer but the way I use to debug those kind of problem.

```
form = ...
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
if form.is_valid():
  ...
```

Run the server and try to submit the form. After submission check the terminal the debugger will hold on import pdb
Then use

`$ form.errors`

Plus don't use semicolons man.

Comment: so i tried this the error that came : (Pdb) {'image': ['This field is required.']}

Answer (score 0):

SO I JUST ADDED THESE LINES TO create.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

you have to declare enctype for file input i suppose

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20394870/8925418
now working just fine